# Java Socket Connection: receiving completely arbitrary integers from the Input Stream

Tags: java, sockets, minecraft, serversocket

I've been learning about sockets in Java to send information between two separate Java applications for a Minigame program I've been working on. The goal is to be able to have it so that Server A can tell Server B to do something by writing and reading ints in a switch statement. This is the code I have for the server-side socket:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try (
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream())
    ) {
        this.output = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
        while (!this.finished) {
            int type = input.readInt();
            this.plugin.getLogger().info("Type: " + type + " from " + this.socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            switch (type) {
                case 1: {
                    ServerManager.getInstance().addActiveServer(this.serverInfo, input.readInt());
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    int length = input.readInt();
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(input.readUTF());
                        PlayerData playerData = PlayerManager.getInstance().getPlayerData(uuid);
                        if (playerData == null) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        playerData.setPlaying(false);
                        playerData.setSpectating(false);
                        playerData.setQueuing(false);
                        playerData.getPlayer().connect(this.plugin.getLobbyServer());
                    }
                    ServerManager.getInstance().addInactiveServer(this.serverInfo);
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    int length = input.readInt();
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        UUID uniqueId = UUID.fromString(input.readUTF());
                        PlayerData playerData = PlayerManager.getInstance().getPlayerData(uniqueId);
                        if (playerData == null) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        playerData.setQueuing(true);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
            }
        }

        this.output.close();
        this.socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When the Minigame begins the countdown sequence, it writes and flushes '1' to the server-side socket before writing and flushing '3' when the Minigame actually starts.

```
// Tells Server A that the max players have been met
// and to start a countdown sequence for a Minigame.
public void sendStartUpdate(int gameKey) {
    try {
        this.output.writeInt(1);
        this.output.writeInt(gameKey);
        this.output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
// Lets Server A know that the player is queued up for a Minigame
public void sendQueuingUpdate(@NotNull Collection<UUID> players) throws IOException {
    this.output.writeInt(3);
    this.output.writeInt(players.size());
    for (UUID player : players) {
        this.output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(player));
    }
    this.output.flush();
}
```

However, for some reason, whenever I run the program, the server first receives '1' and '3' as expected, but then receives a series of really long integers from Server B out of nowhere.

```
[02:45:24 INFO] Type: 1                     // This is good!
[02:45:27 INFO] Type: 3                     // This is good!
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 16777216              // Huh??
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 1280                  // WHAT???
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 256                   // Insert confused guy meme here
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 610548020
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 1667643705
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 925721650
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 842018100
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 878785581
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 1647785059
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 761477426
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 825570148
[02:45:43 INFO] Type: 1647851062
```

This issue also happens when the Minigame ends and the program notifies Server A that the Minigame has ended. I didn't have this problem until I made a slight modification to the code below:

```
public void sendPlayingUpdate(@NotNull Collection<UUID> players) throws IOException {
    this.output.writeBoolean(true);
    this.output.writeBoolean(false);
    this.output.writeBoolean(false);
    this.output.writeInt(5);
    this.output.writeInt(players.size());
    for (UUID player : players) {
        this.output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(player));
    }
//  this.output.writeInt(4);
//  this.output.writeInt(players.size());
//  for (UUID uuid : players) {
//      this.output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(uuid));
//  }
    this.output.flush();
}
```

The commented-out bit is the original code. If I replace it with the uncommented code, it gives all those arbitrarily large integers. Is there a way for another application to somehow connect to the same port as the socket and begin feeding random information? I just don't see how one small minor change can lead to something like 1667643705 being sent, the integers honestly remind me of hashcodes.

I appreciate anything.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a complete sample application running two servers we can copy, compile and run. Like Jeroen said, if you want an answer and not mere speculation, we need something to run and debug. Ideally, share it on GitHub, then you will get a solution for your problem in no time.

Comment: @kriegaex The problem is, this is for a plugin I'm making for a Minecraft server, so I doubt that you'll be able to physically run the code unless you have the necessary servers set up...

Comment: Why not implement a minimal client + server pair in order to just test the socket communication. That is why I said MCVE and not your original application. Just enough to reproduce the problem. To me it seems as if you have full control over both the sending and receiving side of socket communication.

Comment: Frank, why would you set up a bounty and then not provide feedback to those who are trying to help you? Isn't that a kind of waste?

Comment: @kriegaex After a couple of hours of running the program in my mind, I still couldn't figure out why it was giving these arbitrary numbers, so I ended up rewriting the socket-portion of my project. That solved the issue...

Comment: Well, running the program ***in your mind*** was part of the problem, which is exactly why I asked for an MCVE. Debugging the program running ***on a computer*** would have solved it. I am happy you solved your problem, if you feel good about not understanding why it actually occurred, meaning with the next change it could re-occur. I do wonder why you asked the question in the first place and put the bounty on it if you were not interested in a conclusive answer or unwilling to contribute to getting one. But OTOH, I do not need to understand everything in this world. 

Comment: Sending raw ints over a socket on Java seems unnecessary, given that you could have serialized full self-descriptive objects instead, which would have made debugging a breeze. Next time you do this, think "how can I code to make it easier to debug", and only look for run-time efficiency later, if at all.

Comment: @tucuxi When I was doing a bit of research on common issues people had with sockets, I saw a post somewhere where someone said to avoid using object output and input streams to send data (send it as raw data instead). I couldn't find a reason why, but I followed that advice. I ended up switching to object and input streams though when I rewrote the program, which is why this question is a little moot now...

Answer (score 3):

The timestamps indicate a 16 second gap between the second and third packet. So it's likely not the second `3` packet that is corrupt. Somewhere else you are sending a malformed packet in code not presented.

The data is:

```
01 00 00 00  00 00 05 00  00 00 01 00  24 [... load of hex ...]
```

`0x24` is `$`, but could be a string length from a `writeUTF` - say, the two UUIDs concatenated.

I would start off testing the parse code can interpret the output of the format code without all the server stuff. As a benefit, that will require factoring the code better.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your server-side code it seems that your protocol works as follows

- Packet ID (int): 4 bytes
- N bytes of packet-specific content

Your server-side code recognizes 3 different types of packets, and ignores all non-identified packets but does output their Packet ID.

The most likely scenario is that one of your packets isn't being parsed completely, so you have leftover data that it tries to parse as a new packet. I know this isn't a full answer but without your full program this is impossible for me to debug.

I would suggest creating a unit test for your packet handling logic, where you create a DataInputStream containing only a single packet. For each Packet, you check if it is handled correctly, and if you have any leftover data after processing. This should enable you to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bro in my opinion You may have something else running on the same port - check the CMD with netstat -ano, also in Task Manager is possibility to look on current connections. You may have multiple instances sending or listening on the same port or some other application using chosen port number - let's try changing port number and please tell us if something changed. And one more: If anyone use readUTF, the other side must use writeUTF !!!

Comment: Bro U use input.readInt()  - this is wrong!!! Use readUTF !!!